# German letters Ä Ö Ü ß with Matlabcode

Tags: listings, matlab

Edited 16.05.18 17:55
Added the Matlab-code I want to compile.
Adding

I managed to compile the german letters Ä, Ö, Ü, ß in my Matlab code via listings, but now these letters fail to be compiled in the normal text.
Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,bibtotoc,oneside,10pt]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amstext}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[inputencoding=utf8x/latin1]{listingsutf8}
%this package is needed for the matlab code compile

\lstset{
  language=Matlab,
  breaklines=true,
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\tiny,
  numbersep=5pt,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  columns=fullflexible,
  showstringspaces=false,
  commentstyle=\color{gray}\upshape,
  literate=
  {ß}{{\ss}}1,
  }

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{ngerman}

These dont get compiled: Ä Ö Ü ß.
They can still be written like this, but that would take very long in my thesis: \"o, \"a, \"u, \ss.

\lstinputlisting[language=Matlab, firstline=1, lastline=5]{example.m}

\end{document}
```

MATLAB-Code, save as "example.m" in Latex-Folder:

```
%test µ µ µ 
[file,path]=uigetfile('*.*','Bitte Bild auswählen');
Pfad = strcat(path,file); 
im=imread(Pfad);
figure
imshow(im);
```

As you should see now, Latex can compile the Umlaute from the Matlabcode ä, ö, ü and ß, but µ does not work. And in the text none of the Umlaute can be compiled.

Comment: Can you give an example containing some  matlab code that makes it crash?

Comment: Yes i wrote it in an answer below. If u use it the way I described it, you will create the same error message. Removing \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} will output the matlab code, but the Umlaute won't be compiled the right way. Thanks for any help, I've been trying this for a while ;)

Comment: Please do not add new informations in an answer, edit instead your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use the `inputencoding`-option on the `listing` environment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,bibtotoc,oneside,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[inputencoding=utf8]{listingsutf8}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[inputencoding={utf8},extendedchars=true]
Ä Ö Ü ü ä ö
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems to work, but it showed me an ö instead of an ä, so i put extendedchars=true and now its good! Cannot believe it, so i test it a bit ;)

Comment: That was a mistake from my part, sorry.

Comment: You can also put `inputencoding={utf8},extendedchars=true` into the `\lstset`

Comment: Thanks, i accepted this as answer! Can be closed for my part. Great fast help :)

Comment: Great, thanks! The questions here don't really close, just FYI :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you'd use the [`inputenc`](https://ctan.org/pkg/inputenc)-package with `utf8`: `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`. This is for compiling them in LaTeX.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %<--- Add this
\begin{document}
  These now get compiled: Ä Ö Ü ß.
  Also, as you said, these can still be written like \"o, \"a, \"u, \ss.  
  Although, that would take very long in your thesis.
\end{document}
```

Next: You have to add the captial version in the `literate`-part of `\lstset`, as well as the `µ`:

```
\lstset{literate=%
    {Ö}{{\"O}}1
    {Ä}{{\"A}}1
    {Ü}{{\"U}}1
    {ß}{{\ss}}2
    {ü}{{\"u}}1
    {ä}{{\"a}}1
    {ö}{{\"o}}1
    {µ}{{$\mu$}}1
}
```

In so that your `lstset` would be

```
\lstset{
  language=Matlab,
  breaklines=true,
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\tiny,
  numbersep=5pt,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  columns=fullflexible,
  showstringspaces=false,
  commentstyle=\color{gray}\upshape,
  literate=%
    {Ö}{{\"O}}1
    {Ä}{{\"A}}1
    {Ü}{{\"U}}1
    {ß}{{\ss}}2
    {ü}{{\"u}}1
    {ä}{{\"a}}1
    {ö}{{\"o}}1
    {µ}{{$\mu$}}1
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for help! I tried it, but it only works when the line \lstinputlisting[language=Matlab, firstline=14, lastline=14]{Matlabcode.m} stays as comment. I get the error ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char �hl (U+D8). I got Umlaute ä,  ö, ü in the matlab-code  as well, without them it would work.

Comment: I use the µ in a string where i ask the user to input a certain length in µm. Its not a variable. Overall the \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} makes the Umlaute work in the text, and the \usepackage[inputencoding=utf8x/latin1]{listingsutf8} will make them work in the matlab-code. Both together do not seem to work, so i search a way to combine their functions somehow.

Comment: @Patrick Answer updated; It should work fine with MATLAB-code now.

Comment: @Patrick: Answer again updated to fix your µ-problem :)

Comment: This works well, but only if the Matlab-code has no Umlaute or other special characters at all. With the Umlaute in Matlab, I get an error and nothing gets compiled. The literate seems not to work for the matlab-code.

Comment: For the µ in text I recommend `\usepackage{textcomp}` and than `{µ}{{\textmu}}1` in the literate statement.